# Read collection by chunk

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I'm trying to create a module that give me `X` documents of a collection each time I call it.
I want to iterate through all my collection and get the next `X` elements each time I ask it.

I've tried to change the `batch_size()` of a `cursor` but I couldn't make it worked. I tried to set the `limit()` but it wasn't what I wanted.

I managed to get one element each time but I lose too much time and I had to keep the cursor alive.

Is there a function that do what I want ?
Or can you give me hints ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Is it paging of results? Which means getting a set of data in one request and then getting a continued set of data in another request. If this is a single request then why not process `n` items of the cursor, do whatever, and then continue fetching the cursor? Your question is very unclear as to your intent.

Comment: Yes, I want to display my collection in a web page, and I need this module for pagination and I don't want to send 5Gb to my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a combinaison of `skip()` + `limit()` I ended up with one of a easiest solution, it's just hard to find something about it.

So to retrieve a chunk in mongodb, for pagination for example use :

`cursor = db.collection.find()[startItemPosition:stopItemPosition]`

It's giving me a cursor with `stopItemPosition` - `startItemPosition` elements.